# Azure SSL certificate tag

Tags: azure, tags, certificate

I have uploaded an `SSl` certificate on the `azure` portal for my web app. 
Is there a way to add `key-value` `tag` for the cert? From the documentation, I see tags only for `resource-group` etc but not for a particular cert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to see the certificate in your resource group, just add tag as usual.
[image]

On my side, the certificate is hidden because it's managed by Azure. I can show it by clicking the checkbox on top of your resource group.

[image]

If after you click the certificate and there is no `Tags` bar on its panel, you can choose to use cloud shell to add tag. You can find the cloud shell on top right of your portal.
[image]

The first time you run it, you may need to create storage for the shell, just follow the steps azure provides. Then we can add tags. Use powershell script as an example, just two commands to achieve your goal.

`$r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName certificatename -ResourceGroupName resourcegroupname`

`Set-AzureRmResource -Tag @{ TagName="TagValue"} -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force`

Things work on my side. Any further question, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the REST API documentation for [`Create or Update Certificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/createorupdate), looks like it is possible to assign tags to SSL Certificates. I believe this functionality is not exposed on the Portal. I looked up Azure Powershell Cmdlets as well and couldn't find anything there (it is entirely possible that I may have missed out something).

If you need to assign tags to SSL Certificate, you can always use REST API and invoke that API using either writing code or using a tool like Postman. Other thing you should look at is `Azure SDK`. In all likelihood, you will find some functionality there which will let you assign tags to a SSL certificate.